# Is authenticate() deprecated in mongodb jar 3.0.1

Tags: java, mongodb

It created a user for my mongodb database. I have to authenticate it by username and password .I refered and found the code as

```
  DB db = mongo.getDB("database_name");
boolean auth = db.authenticate("username", "password".toCharArray());
```

but shows an error in netbeans at .authenticate function .I have used mongo 3.0.1 jar .Does 3.0.1 doesnot have function.Is there any another way to authenticate user ?

Comment: Referring to MongoDb API, it's deprecated since version 2.13. You need to create Credentials and create Clients using them, see http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/#authentication-optional

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle please tell briefly about credentials in mongodb    

MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, database, password);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), Arrays.asList(credential));
how the username and password to be created and authenticated

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle How to create crendentials and create clients using them ??

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you there, I just can tell you what the site behind the link I gave you states. Never used MongoDb by myself. That's why I didn't write an answer, just a comment. Please refer to the api (use Google to find) for further help.